# Wordpress permalinks directory stripped out on IIS6

Tags: wordpress, iis-6

I am totally stumped on this one. Our permalink structure is stripping out the directory WordPress is installed in. It does not do this when logged into the admin though.

For example.

http://domain.com/site/?page_id=10

Is

http://domain.com/?page_id=10

I've never had this happen, but I'm usually working with a LAMP stack.

Comment: What is the admin address? `/wp-admin/` or `/site/wp-admin/`? I suppose that at Settings/General your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) is set correctly.

Comment: Both addresses are www.example.com/example/ and wp-admin loads under /example and so does the site, but all the links drop the /example/ part of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note to self, always disable all plugins before doing any trouble shooting on WordPress. It turned out to be an https plugin. I must have just lucked out and got a buggy release, because and update just came out that fixes it and it's a highly rated plugin.